# Roku Channel Search API

Tags: roku

I've searched through the [Roku SDK documentation](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+SDK+Documentation) and I don't see a channel search API and the [Web Service API](https://apipub.roku.com/) link doesn't work. Does one exist? If so, can you point me to where/how I would access it? If not, can you point me to an alternative approach for searching channels? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Roku Channel Search"? What do you expect, what do you mean? What "web service api" link?

Comment: A web service API to search for channels that are available on a Roku device.

Answer (score 0):

There is no web service publicly available to browse the RokuCo catalog of apps/channels.

In that the situation is no different than other Apple's AppStore et al. Just like with the other stores, they want to control access at that level.

There is also no access to the "universal search" feature (where keyword search finds video content over multiple providers), one of the crown jewels, it's reserved to Roku proper.